# Way to turn output statements into string types?

Tags: java, string, class, oop

Trying to have some stars print out in a JOptionPane dialog box.
Right now I have a void function doing the star work in my Star class:

```
public void setStars(){

    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++){
        if (j % 2 == 0)
            System.out.print("\n");

        else
            System.out.print("\n ");
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            System.out.print("* ");
    }
}
```

which does what it is supposed, but I can't seem to figure out how to implement this into my already created dialog box which is set up as so:

```
String message = String.format("Knight Name: %s%n"
            + "Knight Health: %d%n"
            + "Knight Battles: %d%n"
            + "Knight Age: %d%n"
            + "Knight Gold: $%d%n",k1.getName(), k1.getHealth(),k1.getNumberBattles(),k1.getAge(),k1.getAmountGold());
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```

any possible ways to move make those output statements in  the for loop and have them return as class string?

Comment: so you want the star pattern to be printing on your dialog box?

Comment: yea @exexzian thats all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to return a String instead of using a void-method, and where you used to print you just append it to the StringBuilder. **PS:** Use StringBuilder instead of String += ... since the latter is really, really slow...

```
public String setStars(){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++){
        if (j % 2 == 0)
            sb.append("\n");

        else
            sb.append("\n ");
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            sb.append("* ");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: awesome that does the trick, I was not aware of string builder

Comment: how would i even use string +=? i tried something like that and all it would do is print out one star

Comment: If you replaced StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); with String str = ""; and replaced each sb.append(....) with str += ... and return str; in the end. But, don't do this. String concat. is really slow like that in Java!